# sql Top 1 vs System.Linq firstordefault

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am rewriting an SProc in c#. the problem is that in SProc there is a query like this:

```
select top 1 *
from ClientDebt
where ClinetID = 11234
order by Balance desc
```

For example :I have a client with 3 debts, all of them have same balance. the debt ids are : 1,2,3

c# equivalent of that query is :

```
debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.Balance)
     .FirstOrDefault()
```

debts represent clients 3 debts

the interesting part is that sql return debt with Id 2 but c# code returns Id 1.
The Id 1 make sense for me But in order to keep code functionality the same I need to change the c# code to return middle one.

I do not sure what is the logic behind sql top 1 where several rows match the query.

The query will select one debt and update the database. I would like the linq to return the same result with sql

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you look into SQL that is generated by LINQ and compare it against your `TOP 1` solution?

Comment: after the balance field in order by clause it uses the primary key next causing it to return 1 in sql

Comment: Did you not notice your SQL has a WHERE that your Linq statement does not? Is this 1 : 1 or is there more to the story? And are you oprating in-memory or is the Linq statement going to be sent to the DB? Please provide more information.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I did not mention that that debts in linq are debts with that clinetId, sorry for the confusion

Comment: technically the SQL syntax is `select top (1) *` for SQL Server but it lets you get away with the one without the parenthesis.

Comment: what does your class for `debts` look like?  Specifically the type (and sql type) for `Balance` here;

Answer (score 1):

```
debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.Balance).ThenByDescending(d => d.Id)
     .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this will order by Id  and this is not what I am after, for example this return a row with Id 3 , but sql returns a row with Id 2

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.
How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can start SQL Profiler, execute stored procedure, review result, and then catch query which application send through linq, and again review result.

Also, you can easily view execution plan of you procedure, and try it to optimize, but with linq query, you cannot easily do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try Take(1) before firstordefault.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK, IN SQL if you select rows without ORDER BY, it orders the resultset based on the primary key.
With Order BY CLAUSE [field], implicitly next order is [primarykey].

Comment: That is not true, if you omit ORDER BY clause, then you will get something what are called real relation, which follow basic rule of set theory, THERE IS NO PARICULAR ORDER OF SET ELEMENTS. By the way, often will be case that result without ORDER BY will be ordered by primary key, or clustered index, but there is no guarantee for that.

Comment: @veljasije - There is no guarantee, but it will behave like this 100% of the time. Easy with the downvotes

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not downvoting answer neither once, just commenting ;) It's likely to be sorted, even on few different machines, but what if you don't have primary key on table, then especially doesn't havesorted result. Read about set theory in SQL, it will clarifies you what I'm saying.

Comment: @Downvoters, please care to comment. There is a difference between theory and actuality.

Comment: I down-voted because I believe it is wrong. If the database has fields such as id, ClientID, Balance and Date and has an index on ClientID and Date, then (unless the dataset is very small) Sql should use the index to perform the selection and without an explicit orderby it will probably return the results in Date order. (And if I seen any code that was assuming this, I would change it)